# onblur event doesn't fire in Chrome when clicking on disabled button element - works in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a disabled button that should become enabled when there is text in an input element. The code to enable/disable the button is in the `onblur` event of the input. My HTML consists of an `input` with `id="in"`, a `button` with attribute `disabled="disabled"` and a `span` with `id="sp"`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $("#in").bind("blur",function(){
        alert("blur");
        if($("#in").attr("value").length > 0){
            $("button")[0].disabled = false;   
        } else {
            $("button")[0].disabled = true;
        }        
    });

    $("#in").bind("focusout",function(){
        alert("focusout");
        if($("#in").attr("value").length > 0){
            $("button")[0].disabled = false;   
        } else {
            $("button")[0].disabled = true;
        }        
    });

    $("button").click(function(){
        count++;
        $("#sp").text(count);
    });
});
```

In IE 9, if I type text into the input element and click on the disabled button, the input's `onblur` fires, the button becomes enabled, and I get the button's click event.
However, in Chrome, when I type text into the input element and click on the disabled button, nothing at all happens.

Is there some property of the button I'm overlooking? I tried to get the `focusout` to fire, but I get the same result. I also get the same result using Firefox. Chrome seems to treat the `disabled` attribute more strictly than IE, but this is going to cause problems with our users. How can I get the `onblur` (or some equivalent) event to fire when I click off the input element onto a disabled button?

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. You might want to check it out, and see if that does what you want it to.

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome, disabled buttons have all event listeners removed from them. Clicking, right clicking, selectstarting, etc. doesn't work on disabled buttons. This means that the focus doesn't leave the input when you click the disabled button. What you can do is manually disable the button via `class="disabled"`, and adding some styles to make it look disabled. Here is an example of CSS you could use to make the button look disabled:

```
button.disabled,
button.disabled:hover,
button.disabled:active,
button.disabled:focus {
    color:gray;
    background:#EEE;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    border-radius:3px;
    outline:none;
}
```

I've made a JSFiddle that shows this **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NhELd/)**. Also note that I've changed the code that toggles the disabled class now, instead of the disabled attribute, and I've put an `if` statement in your button click event handler, so that it doesn't fire when the button is disabled.

Comment: Why does this happen? Why does Chrome remove all event listeners on disabled buttons? This makes no sense, as it is relatively easy to apply a `preventDefault` and/or `stopPropagation`. Also, Firefox and even IE do not do this, though in IE it may have been an oversight.

Comment: @trysis I must say I don't know. The only thing I could find on the web standards is that ["A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events (...) from being dispatched on the element."](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute) so Chrome might have taken that specification and applied it to all events. Applying it to click, mousedown, keydown, etc. only makes sense, so I can understand if they simply apply it to every single event listener as well.

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2368