# react-select remove focus when disabled

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Using `react-select` 3.1.0

I have a filter panel in which 3 select drop-downs cascade to choose the make/model/series for a car.

[image]

The general idea is that you can only select a model *after* make has been selected, and only select a series *after* model. If you change the make it will reset the following options.

That all works fine... except (as you'll see in the GIF below) the focus on the "series" select box remains despite it being disabled.

Any ideas on how I can remove that focus? Here's what my code looks like (each box is essentially the same):

```
            <Select
                id="series-select"
                data-selenium-test="series-select"
                isDisabled={state.model === null}
                isSearchable={false}
                options={series}
                value={selection}
                placeholder="All Series"
                isClearable
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                onChange={/* istanbul ignore next */ (option) => setSeries(option ? option.value : null)}

                // handles edge-case where menu is open but MAKE/MODEL is cleared
                menuIsOpen={state.model === null ? false : undefined}
            />
```

Comment: Maybe this is why? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860061/551436

Comment: I opened a GitHub issue as well, this may be a bug: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4255

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping by `setTimeout()` with empty time prop in the body of `onChange` function solved this issue for me. I've made this for first two inputs.

So for you it should looks like this:

```
 onChange={(option) =>  setTimeout(() => {setSeries(option ? option.value : null)})}
```

Also you can use `blurInputOnSelect` prop, but there would be some cases, where issue would be reproduced